# way to parse my json in java

Tags: java, json

I want to parse my json string at run time. But, the problem is my json string is not a valid one due to some issues. Is there any way to parse the json with validation. My json string looks like this:

```
{"page_1":"{\"city\":\"Delhi\",\"locality\":\"Alaknanda\",\"Name_of_Person\":\"Varun Patil\",\"User_email_address\":\"varun.vap@gmail.com\",\"user_phone_number\":\"\",\"sub_locality\":\"\",\"street_name\":\"Pune\",\"home_plot_no\":\"xyz\",\"pin_code\":\"411060\",\"project_society_build_name\":\"\",\"landmark_reference_1\":\"\",\"landmark_reference_2\":\"\",\"No_of_Schools\":20,\"No_of_Hospitals\":20,\"No_of_Metro\":0,\"No_of_Mall\":20,\"No_of_Park\":20,\"Distance_of_schools\":1.51,\"Distance_of_Hospitals\":2.5,\"Distance_of_Metro\":0,\"Distance_of_Mall\":1.9,\"Distance_of_Park\":1.1,\"lat\":28.5304408,\"lng\":77.2505733,\"ipinfo\":{\"ip\":\"59.88.97.45\",\"hostname\":\"No Hostname\",\"city\":\"Pune\",\"region\":\"Maharashtra\",\"country\":\"IN\",\"loc\":\"18.5333,73.8667\",\"org\":\"AS9829 National Internet Backbone\",\"postal\":\"411001\"}}","page_2":"{\"home_type\":\"Flat\",\"area\":\"1000\",\"beds\":\"2 BHK\",\"bath_rooms\":2,\"building_age\":\"3\",\"floors\":\"\",\"balcony\":1,\"amenities\":\"regular\",\"amenities_options\":{\"gated_security\":\"\",\"physical_security\":\"\",\"cctv_camera\":\"\",\"controll_access\":\"\",\"elevator\":\"\",\"power_back_up\":\"\",\"parking\":\"\",\"partial_parking\":\"\",\"onsite_maintenance_store\":\"\",\"open_garden\":\"\",\"party_lawn\":\"\",\"amenities_balcony\":\"\",\"club_house\":\"\",\"fitness_center\":\"\",\"swimming_pool\":\"\",\"party_hall\":\"\",\"tennis_court\":\"\",\"basket_ball_court\":\"\",\"squash_coutry\":\"\",\"amphi_theatre\":\"\",\"business_center\":\"\",\"jogging_track\":\"\",\"convinience_store\":\"\",\"guest_rooms\":\"\"},\"interior\":\"regular\",\"interior_options\":{\"tiles\":\"\",\"marble\":\"\",\"wooden\":\"\",\"modular_kitchen\":\"\",\"partial_modular_kitchen\":\"\",\"gas_pipe\":\"\",\"intercom_system\":\"\",\"air_conditioning\":\"\",\"partial_air_conditioning\":\"\",\"wardrobe\":\"\",\"sanitation_fixtures\":\"\",\"false_ceiling\":\"\",\"partial_false_ceiling\":\"\",\"recessed_lighting\":\"\"},\"location\":\"regular\",\"location_options\":{\"good_view\":\"\",\"transporation_hub\":\"\",\"shopping_center\":\"\",\"hospital\":\"\",\"school\":\"\",\"ample_parking\":\"\",\"park\":\"\",\"temple\":\"\",\"bank\":\"\",\"less_congestion\":\"\",\"less_pollution\":\"\"},\"maintenance\":\"\",\"maintenance_value\":\"\",\"near_by\":{\"school\":\"\",\"hospital\":\"\",\"mall\":\"\",\"park\":\"\",\"metro\":\"\"},\"city\":\"Delhi\",\"locality\":\"Alaknanda\",\"token\":\"9a2a8bf359494054f98c80009b5bd0e7\"}"}
```

I tried the following methods:

```
String result = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(jsonstring, "UTF-8");
String withCharacters = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(jsonstring);

JSONObject json = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(jsonstring);
System.out.println("city=" + json.get("city"));
System.out.println("locality=" + json.get("locality"));
```

Nothing works for me and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That is valid json containing 1 string element with as key `page_1`.

Comment: As @Ferrybig said, That's a valid JSON! You can validate it online using any of the validators.

Comment: try http://jsonlint.com/. I checked your json is valid. Whats the issue?

Comment: You know that you have some nested json objects, don't you? So you first need to get the page and then the city. Besides that, I saw multiple questions on exactly the same lines in the last few days - is this a university assignment?

Answer (score 0):

You have some escaped json inside your main json structure. That means it's valid json, but after parsing the main structure you have to parse the value of `page_1` (and probably all remaining `page`s as well). Try this:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json = (JSONObject)parser.parse(jsonstring);
JSONObject nestedJson = (JSONObject)parser.parse(json.get("page_1"));
System.out.println("city=" + nestedJson.get("city"));
```